# Complex meta query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have very complex meta query that breaks into two part. Each part working fine alone but when I compare both part with or it should show me combination of both result(s), but its not showing anything.

**First snippet**

```
array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'range1_min',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'range1_max',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    ),
    array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'range1_min',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'range1_max',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    )
);
```

**Second snippet**

```
array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'range2_min',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'range2_max',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    ),
    array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'range2_min',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'range2_max',
            'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
            'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    )
);
```

Individually they both are working fine, but when I put them together with **"OR"** condition they are not working.

**Full code snippet**

```
array(
    'relation'      => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'range1_min',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'range1_max',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '>='
            )
        ),
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'range1_min',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'range1_max',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '>='
            )
        )
    ) ,
    array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'range2_min',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'range2_max',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['m']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '>='
            )
        ),
        array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'range2_min',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'range2_max',
                'value'     => floatval($_GET['n']),
                'type'      => 'DECIMAL',
                'compare'   => '>='
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your Wordpress version

Comment: I knew it someone will definitely ask this question, if any of snippet works alone that means I am using wordpress 4.1+. Here I am using wordpress 4.1.

Comment: Ok, sorry for asking then

Comment: You have a really bad and mean attitude towards people that are interested in helping you. No wonder no one else has tried helping you.

Comment: Sorry but you've taken me wrong. I was just trying to tell what I was expecting. May that is one of your perception, not the guy who have commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I generate sql query of wordpress and run it on phpmyadmin, it generate error and saying that I have exceeded default join setting, means in my query I have too many join.

I have resolve this error by manually put this sql query before my wordpress query.

```
global $wpdb
$wpdb->query("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1");
```